# jQuery get number after | from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box where I want value to be inserted in below format

```
name|qty
name2|qty2
```

In want to get value of qty+qty2+.... so on all quantity in textarea after `|`,
next product are in new line

```
<textarea onchange=gettotal()></textarea>
```

How I parse textarea value to get all qty? pls help

Comment: Can you add your current `gettotal` implementation? Or have you tried anything else so far?

Comment: i tried to do via php pass value to other page via jquery post , but it's longer way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. You can get your input via `getElementById`.

```
function getTotal() {

    var input = "james|50\nmike|30"
    var inputs = input.split("\n");
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++){
     qty = parseInt((inputs[i].split("|"))[1]);
     total += qty;
    }
    alert (total);


}
```

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget however he's using this, he'd need to have input be the value of the textarea in question. 


var input = document.getElementById(<element in question>).value;